# Найти число различных элементов массива

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Как найти?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *a, i, j, n, count=1; bool f = true;
    cout<<"Razmernost' n = "; cin>>n;
    a = new int [n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"a["<<i+1<<"] = "; cin>>a[i];
        }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<n; j++){
            if(a[i]!=a[j]){
                count++;
                }
        } 
    }

    cout<<"Kol-vo razn. elem. = "<<count;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Что не правильно в программе?

Comment: @relike, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я вот сейчас делаю его, т.к. точно не могу сказать что вытворял мой код. Я понимаю. Я сначало то выложил его, но там был вообще уж бред (мною исправленная программы :DDD )

Comment: Я добавил код.

Comment: if(a[i]!=a[j]){count++;} не правильно

Comment: ну это я понял. А какое должно быть условие?

Comment: Очевидно же, что  bool f = true; вы не просто так определили, так воспользуетесь этим "переключателем"

Comment: Вот вам однострочник на C#:

    new HashSet<int>(a).Count

Переведите его на С++ и пользуйтесь.

Comment: @VladD, set<int>(a.begin(), a.end()).size()

Comment: @dzhioev: точно! Но для этого случая скорее `(a, a + n)`.

Answer (score 1):

можно решать так же как сопряженную задача,а именно, сколько совпадений. Сортируете массив, и делаете 1 проход. Ну а функцию считающую совпадения организовываете как машину состояний. Вот псевдо-код :

```
int flag = 2
while(flag != 3)
{
if(flag == 2)
{
int i = next_element;
flag = 1;
new_element++;
}
if(next_element == i && flag == 1)
{
     if(next_element == i){next_element = get_next_element();flag = 1;}
     if(next_element != i) flag = 2;
     if(next_element == null)flag = 3;
}
}
```

примерно так должна выглядеть ваша функция. **new_element** - это кол-во различных элементов

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка необязательна

```
  vector<int> v(N);
................
//заполнение  v
................
  vector<bool> flow(N, false);
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    if(!flow[i])
    {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
      {
        if(!flow[j] && v[i] == v[j])
          flow[j] = true;
        else
          count++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Просто с сортировкой может быть сложность O(n * log n + n), а у Вас - O(n^2/2)

Comment: А сама сортировка не в счет?

Comment: вы о чем? Оо

Comment: @BuilderC, cортировка как раз и даёт O(n * log n. Основной цикл превращается в if (x[i] != x[i-1])  count++



@voipp, o "*Сортировка необязательна*"

Comment: Да, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Есть много способов

1) Самый очевидный - перебор за **O(N^2)**

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    bool fl = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (i != j && a[i] == a[j]) {
          fl = false;
          break;
        }
    if (fl) k++;
}
cout << k;
```

2) Оптимизация с сортировкой за **O(N*log(N))**

```
int k = 0;
sort(a, a + n);
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (a[i] != a[i-1] && a[i] != a[i+1]) k++;
if (n == 1) k = 1;
if (a[0] != a[1] && n > 1) k++;
if (a[n-1] != a[n-2] && n > 1) k++;
cout << k;
```

3) Компактно и понятно через `map` за **O(N*log(N))**, хотя медленнее второго варианта *(константа больше)*

```
int k = 0;
map<int, int> list;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) list[a[i]]++;
for (auto i : list) if (i.second == 1) k++;
cout << k;
```

ПС для новичков

Один из вариантов выше вставлять сюда

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>  //надо в 3-м способе

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];

    //--- сюда вставлять код одного из вариантов выше ---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
const int N = 10;
    int arr[N]{ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 10, 12, 11, 7 }; 

    int there;
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        bool have = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && (i != j || i > j || j > i))  
            {
                there = arr[i];
                x++;
                if (arr[j] == there)
                {
                    x--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i == j)
            {
                have = true;
                there = arr[i];
                x++;

            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"AMOUNT X: "<< x <<"\n\n";

    return 0;

}
```